# Why peer connection state doesnt change from new?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webrtc

I am working with webRTC and wrtc on the server. My client side code is :

```
 React.useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      pc = new RTCPeerConnection()
      const offer = await pc.createOffer()
      await pc.setLocalDescription(offer)
      const { data } = await axios.post('http://localhost:3000/testing', { sdp: pc.localDescription })
      await pc.setRemoteDescription(data.sdp)
  
    })()
    setInterval(() => {
      console.log(pc.connectionState)
    }, 2222);
  }, []);
```

And the server side is :

```
server.post('/testing', async function (req, res) {
  const { sdp } = req.body
  const pc = new webrtc.RTCPeerConnection()
    await pc.setRemoteDescription(sdp)
    const answer = await pc.createAnswer()
    await pc.setLocalDescription(answer)
    res.status(200).json({ sdp: pc.localDescription })
})
```

`pc.connectionState` indicates `new` and apparently I am not connected. Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not adding any tracks or a datachannel hence your SDP contains no m= sections, no ice candidates are gathered and nothing useful happens.

Comment: So there is no way to make webRTC connections without tracks?

Comment: If you don't intend to do anything with the connection, why establish it? You can use addTransceiver to "reserve" space but be careful with premature optimization.

Comment: That makes sense. Appreciate it.